# Python: as yet undefined variable called in function - but works?

Tags: python, function, variables, undefined

I am still new to Python and have been reviewing the following code not written by me.

Could someone please explain how the first instance of the variable "clean" is able to be be called in the check_arguments function?  It seems to me as though it is calling an as yet undefined variable.  The code works but shouldn't that call to "clean" produce an error?

To be clear the bit I am referring to is this.

```
def check_arguments(ages):
    clean, ages_list = parse_ages_argument(ages)
```

The full code is as follows...

```
def check_arguments(ages):
    clean, ages_list = parse_ages_argument(ages)
    if clean != True:
        print('invalid ages: %s') % ages
    return ages_list

def parse_ages_argument(ages):
    clean = True
    ages_list = []
    ages_string_list = ages.split(',')
    for age_string in ages_string_list:
        if age_string.isdigit() != True:
            clean = False
            break
    for age_string in ages_string_list:
        try:
            ages_list.append(int(age_string))
        except ValueError:
            clean = False
            break

    ages_list.sort(reverse=True)
    return clean, ages_list

ages_list = check_arguments('1,2,3')
print(ages_list)
```

Comment: Unable to understand your problem here. What do you mean by "called in the check_arguments function". clean is a variable. How is it being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how the first instance of the variable "clean" is able to be be called in the check_arguments function?

This is a nonsensical thing to ask in the first place, since variables aren't called; functions are. Further, "instance" normally means "a value that is of some class type", not "occurrence of the thing in question in the code listing".

That said: the line of code in question does not use an undefined variable `clean`. It **defines** the variable `clean` (and `ages_list` at the same time). `parse_ages_argument` returns two values (as you can see by examining its `return` statement). The two returned values are assigned to the two variables, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Karl.  Whilst Ignacio's answer and link is obviously accurate I have chosen yours as the accepted answer as it helped me understand specifically whats going on in this code (from a newbie perspective).  Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't have a comma operator. What you are seeing is [**sequence unpacking**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> print a, b
1 2
```

Comment: I can imagine this being confusing for a beginner, especially since it's the return value of a function being sequence unpacked. I'd suggest he replaces `clean, ages_list =` with `test_ret_val =` and then `print test_ret_val` to understand what's going on.